# Java - = Operator doesn't work on a Class in a `@Controller`

Tags: java, spring

I have a Class `Message` that is a `@ModelAttribute` in a `@Controller` method. When I do `message = some_message_object` inside the method, it doesn't throw any error, but the value of `message` doesn't change. Instead, I have to do this:

```
if(some_message_object != null) {
    message.setId(some_message_object.getId()) ;
    message.setFrom(some_message_object.getFrom()) ;
    message.setTo(some_message_object.getTo()) ;
}
```

After this, `message` is same as `some_message_object`. Please help me if I'm using `=` wrong.

**EDIT**

This is the original code:

```
@RequestMapping("/readmessage")
public String readMessage(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message {
    some_message_object = someService.getMessage() ;
    message = some_message_object ;
}
```

Comment: Changing a method parameter reference to an object inside a method won't affect references to the object *outside* the method. Without seeing your actual code it's difficult to guess, but it's likely you've misunderstood how method parameters work.

Comment: I've explained everything that my actual code does. Could you help me understand *how method parameters work* i.e. how would you do what i'm trying to do? (what i'm trying is simple. i'm trying to use `=` operator on a method parameter that happens to be a class)

Comment: Is message a local variable? Or post some more code..

Comment: @LewsTherin `message` is a `@ModelAttribute` that goes in as an argument to a `@RequestMapping` method in a `@Controller`

Comment: You said what the method does, but you didn't show what you're actually doing, i.e., trying to change a reference outside a method from inside a method. No reason to not include the actual scenario, since it can be demonstrated by adding the method/parameter declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, in your case, would be to set the attribute like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/readmessage")
public String readMessage(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message,
  ModelMap map) {
    some_message_object = someService.getMessage() ;
    map.addAttribute("message", some_message_object) ;
}
```

This way, you dont have to worry about `message`. It's clean and easy :)

Comment: Man, that worked like magic. Cant believe no one thought about such a simple solution :D thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Java does not pass method parameters by reference: modifying the parameter of a method only modifies the local variable, and *not* the variable in the calling method. You can, however, modify the object's content by calling methods on it, as you did.

Supposing you have

```
@Controller
public void method(@ModelAttribute Message message) {
    message = some_message_object;
}
```

message can be seen as a local variable to the method, and the modification is also local. You can only call methods on parameters, not modify them directly (well, you can, but that modification is not seen by the caller).

---

If you have multiple attributes to copy from one object to another, you can either add an update method to your Message:

```
public void update(Message message) {
    this.field1 = message.field1;
    this.field2 = message.field2;
    // ...
}
```

or use a bean mapper such as [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), which uses reflection.

Comment: But I dont wanna be doing this for classes that have like 20 setter methods. the code would get really cluttered. besides, it's clearly not the way of doing things. Could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Is there any way I can do something in the class, like operator overloading, to work around this?

Comment: @tg3an0maly "Clearly"? Actually it is, although you can use things liked bean utils, dozer, etc. to keep the mainline code cleaner. Better yet, *return* the modified object and keep the code a but more functionally-oriented.

Comment: There's no operator overloading in Java.

Comment: @DaveNewton I usually *avoid* returning a modified object; I'm not as strict as Betrand Meyers, but I either return a *new* object or mutate the current one (and return a status and/or void but generally *not* the object mutated). Granted, there are some cases like "Builder Pattern" changing where returning a mutated object is handy ..

Comment: so how would you go about "mutating" the `message` object so that it can be used in my views?

Comment: @pst Yep, yep, got tired of typing on my mobile device :)

Comment: @th3an0maly As you did it, or as how myself or pst described, either using a utility to make it easier, or not.

Comment: Besides, if message is a HTTP request parameter, what do you expect to happen when you modify it?